# How can I check the maximum value from a set of tables in SQL Server (if possible)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a set of databases (80 in total). Every single one has a table called tblProfessions. The tables are not standardized. For example:

EDIT: all the databases are on the same server.

The DB1.dbo.tblProfessions is like:

| intProfessionCode | strProfessionDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | lawyer |
| 2 | dentist |
| ... | ... |
| 30 | doctor |

And the DB72.dbo.tblProfessions is as follows:

| intProfessionCode | strProfessionDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | designer |
| 2 | butcher |
| ... | ... |
| 80 | chef |

Suppose I ran a script from DBO1 to DBO72, and I found that the biggest table has 80 entries (in this case the DBO72 is the biggest one).

By my limited knowledge, all I know is to run the below script database by database, and write it down in a spreadsheet manually:

```
SELECT MAX(intProfessionCode) FROM [DB].dbo.tblProfessions;
```

Is there a script to run and loop through all the tblProfessions and get the one with the most entries? All I want is the biggest number found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all of these databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes. All of them.

Comment: Is there a reason for having 80 database?

Comment: Each one represents a different school.

Comment: Bad database design then.

Comment: @SalmanA not necessarily a bad design. Sounds like a single tenant database and they have a bunch of clients. Single tenants databases can sometimes be awful but so can a multi-tenant architecture. They both have pros and cons.

Comment: @SalmanA If the databases hold personal data, then there could additionally be legal requirements for keeping the data segregated. In such a case definitely not bad database design. There is not enough information to make such a sweeping statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
WITH dat 
AS
(
SELECT 'db1' AS database_name, MAX(intProfessionCode) AS max_intProfessionCode
FROM DB1.dbo.tblProfessions
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db72' AS database_name, MAX(intProfessionCode) AS max_intProfessionCode
FROM DB72.dbo.tblProfessions
)
SELECT dat.db, dat.max_intProfessionCode
FROM dat
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(max_intProfessionCode) AS max_intProfessionCode_overall 
            FROM dat) y 
            ON dat.max_intProfessionCode = y.max_intProfessionCode_overall
```

For situations like this, I usually query the catalog to write the above script rather than typing it out:

```
    WITH
    dat AS
    (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''' AS db,
    MAX(intProfessionCode) AS max_intProfessionCode 
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME('dbo') + '.' + QUOTENAME('tblProfessions') + ' 
    UNION ALL',' ') AS s
    FROM sys.databases s
    WHERE s.name LIKE 'DB%' --EDIT APPROPRIATELY
    )
    SELECT 'WITH dat 
AS
(' + SUBSTRING(s,1,LEN(s) - LEN(' UNION ALL')) + ')
SELECT dat.db, dat.max_intProfessionCode
FROM dat
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(max_intProfessionCode) AS max_intProfessionCode_overall 
            FROM dat) y 
            ON dat.max_intProfessionCode = y.max_intProfessionCode_overall' AS scrpt
    FROM dat;
```

Make sure the above is only returning data for the appropriate databases by editing the `WHERE` clause in the CTE, then copy the output, paste elsewhere and run it to get your results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your script worked fine!

Comment: @GuilhermeMassoqueto, if the script solved your problem, please consider voting on and accepting the answer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers